# How to remove DHTMLX Gantt Duration Offset of 1

Tags: phpmyadmin, dhtmlx

I have a Gantt that shows the duration of current projects. This gantt is loading the data from a phpmyadmin database. 
In my database there is for example an id: 1 text: project1 start_date: 2020-02-28 00:00:00 duration: 0
So it should display this task with a duration of 0. All projects with duration of 0 and this start_date are starting one day before so 2020-02-27 and the task is shown with a duration of 1.

```
  gantt.config.date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"; 
   gantt.config.duration_unit = "hour"

gantt.config.scales = [
    {unit: "month", step: 1, format: "%F, %Y"},
    {unit: "week", step: 1, format: function (date) {
        return "Week #" + gantt.date.getWeek(date);
    }},
    {unit: "day", step: 1, format: "%D", css: function(date) {
    if(!gantt.isWorkTime({ date: date, unit: "day"})){
            return "weekend"
        }
    }}
];

    gantt.config.work_time = true; 
    gantt.templates.scale_cell_class = function(date){
        if(!gantt.isWorkTime(date)){
      return "weekend";
        }
    };
// 0 refers to Sunday, 6 - to Saturday
    gantt.ignore_time = function(date){
   if(date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6)
    return true;
        };


gantt.init("gantt_here"); 
gantt.load("/api/data");

var dp = new gantt.dataProcessor("/api");
dp.init(gantt);
dp.setTransactionMode("REST");
```

Worktime is from 0 to 8 (8 hours) and from monday to friday. I dont know why i have an offset of +1 hour in duration and an offset of -1 day at the start_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project tasks ignore the predefined date parameters(`start_date`, `end_date`, `duration`) and obtain those parameters from their children. If there are no child tasks, projects will try to obtain the dates from other tasks. If there are only `project` tasks in the chart, Gantt will assign the current date to the projects.

Unfortunately, there is no way to change how it works. You can change the width of the project task by using the `task_class` template:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_task_class_template.html

For example:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/cecc50a97

But you won't be able to change the dates.

You need to use a different task type or implement a custom solution.